# Team Foundation Server unreadable email format

Tags: email, tfs, notifications, format, continuous-integration

I've setup TFS notifications for when a Build Breaks and it works but the email is malformed and full of Asian characters:

[image]

I'm assuming there is a locale setting causing it?

I don't have access to the SMTP server but its unlikely anyone else is encountering malformed messages. Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: To the person decided to mark this as off-topic, because TFS is a programming tool this is on-topic.

Comment: Have you ever customized the format for TFS email alerts? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-customize-alerts#customize-the-format-for-tfs-email-alerts, If you didn't change the format file, you can try to check your system locale settings, try to change it to English,or other Asian languages to check if the characters can be displayed correctly.

Comment: No, I did check the files XML and plaintext existed but didn't touch the build email template or any others.

Comment: Does anybody else have the same issue or just it appears for yourself ? Based on the screenshot your are using HTML format for the notification, what about the plaintext format? You can try to clean the caches in Application Tier machine, then restart the IIS for tfs site, then try it again.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT SRS 117062715951597, thanks I'll try clear the cache and restart IIS, yes everyone in my team gets the encoded messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I logged my very first Microsoft case for this one, *brings back memories*.</sub>

## Solution 1

The MSFT Engineer found a similar case:

> TFS Notifications and alerts are UTF 16 encoded and they are garbled.

[image]

**The solution is to remove the privacy tag from the emails on the exchange server.**

Alternatively use a 3rd party smtp server.

<sub>I cannot attempt either of these in the locked down environment I work in but I thought share if it helps someone else in the future.</sub>

## Solution 2

I found a similar thread on MSDN [TFS 2012 sends Chinese characters in emails, breaking HTML alerts for all users](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2c645ca-9681-4274-bfa9-465a56e2afde/tfs-2012-sends-chinese-characters-in-emails-breaking-html-alerts-for-all-users?forum=tfsgeneral).

The (TFS2012) solution is to edit the TeamFoundation.xsl file(s). This solution works for TFS2017, except you need to edit the BuildCompleteEvent.xsl and TeamFoundation.xsl files in the directory:

**%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033**

1. In the BuildCompleteEvent.xsl switch html to xml in 2 places:

> <?xml version='1.0'?> <?xsl:stylesheet
>   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
>   xmlns:tb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2010/Build"
>   xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">   <?xsl:import href="TeamFoundation.xsl"/>   <?xsl:output
>   method = "**xml**" doctype-public ="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>
>   <?xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="**xml**"/>

2. In the TeamFoundation.xsl switch html to xml:

> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>   <xsl:output method="**xml**"/>

3. It is important you do a IISReset or a Reboot the TFS server for the changes to take affect.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT - not sure if you saw the SRS case notes? As I said it isn't feasible for me to remove the legal/privacy email footer or use a 3rd party SMTP server in the organisation where I work. So I dont know if it works and I don't have a workaround. I posted in good faith that it will help someone who can try either workaround.

Comment: Just can think of that the problems should be caused by SMTP server or Alert template, it worth have a try to backup the alert template first then replace with the normal ones from another TFS server.

Comment: What I want Andy is a fix from the Exchange Team or Brian Harry's TFS team, why is one encoded utf-8 and the other injects a charset utf-16, answer that and provide a fix I'll give you 200 bounty. Really appreciate your help mate, I'm desperate