# Build Notification does not working in TFS

Tags: tfs, build, notifications, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Currently I have an issue with notification emails after building. It was absolutely working fine a few days ago, but now it does not trigger the email after successful a build. We found the difference in the email template for the build process. The email trigger is not working after code is checked-in but works fine after a manual build from TFS environment.

Could you please help us to figure out the issue?

Comment: Can you show screenshots of what you have setup? Is this TFS On-Prem? What version? When you changed the Email Template, what did you change? I've had to [edit them myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44795267/495455). To troubleshoot it start off by enabling pipeline tracing in your Exchange server: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj916678(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: I just got resposne from Microsoft.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168969/build-notifications-have-stopped.html

Comment: Response:
This seems like a know issue right now, the below link will help with more information.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168969/build-notifications-have-stopped.html

 

Recently the email notification format has been changed and looks like the issue is happening after that, and our PG team is working on this to release a hotfix to resolve it.

 

Hopefully the issue will be resolved soon.